# No outbound connection from the WFE to the web service hosted server from an InfoPath form hosted in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, web-services, forms-services

Bit of a background:

- Dev Enviornment - 1 X WFE/App Server, 1 X DB server
- UAT Enviornment - 1 X WFE, 1 X App Server and 1 X DB Server

We have an infopath form published to a form library, using a data connection which is in the Data connection library (which has been approved). The data connection file is a simple ucdx file generated by InfoPath when creating a connection. It connects to a anonymously accessible web service to get some information.

**Issue:**
Works in Dev enviornment **but does not work in UAT**. We have used wireshark to see the netowrk traffic and there is no connection going out to the server hosting the web service. This is from the ULS log file:

InfoPath Settings under Configure form settings:

- Increased timeout, did not make a difference, just meant that the error that poped up took a lot longer
- Allow user form templates to use authentication information contained in data connection files - CHECKED
- Allow cross-domain data access for user form templates that use connection settings in a data connection file - Checked

UAT/DEV WFE settings:

- Loop back disabled
- web service accessible from UAT and DEV on all servers

This is from the ULS logs:

```
03/20/2013 13:45:41.01  w3wp.exe (0x0538)   
0x0E04  InfoPath Forms Services Runtime - Data Connections  6qh7    Verbose Web Request: Begins url=http://webservice.com:7863/INTERFACE/INTERFACE action=http://interface.com/DisposalsValidation  3f60b8ac-bf8a-45c7-a313-09e824ad0ab6  

03/20/2013 13:45:41.01  w3wp.exe (0x0538)   0x0E04  InfoPath Forms Services Runtime - Data Connections  13zc    Verbose Web Request:  Preparing SOAP message    3f60b8ac-bf8a-45c7-a313-09e824ad0ab6  

03/20/2013 13:45:41.01  w3wp.exe (0x0538)   0x0E04  InfoPath Forms Services Runtime - Data Connections  13zd    Verbose Web Request:  Preparing WebRequest  3f60b8ac-bf8a-45c7-a313-09e824ad0ab6  
03/20/2013 13:45:41.01  w3wp.exe (0x0538)   0x0E04  InfoPath Forms Services Runtime - Data Connections  1dhr    Verbose Web Request:  Writing request stream    3f60b8ac-bf8a-45c7-a313-09e824ad0ab6  
03/20/2013 13:45:41.01  w3wp.exe (0x0538)   0x0E04  InfoPath Forms Services Runtime - Data Connections  13zf    Verbose Web Request:  Getting response  3f60b8ac-bf8a-45c7-a313-09e824ad0ab6  
03/20/2013 13:45:41.03  w3wp.exe (0x0538)   0x0E04  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Site=/  3f60b8ac-bf8a-45c7-a313-09e824ad0ab6  

03/20/2013 13:45:51.06  w3wp.exe (0x0538)   0x0E04  InfoPath Forms Services Runtime - Data Connections  13zg    Verbose Web Request:  WebException Caught   3f60b8ac-bf8a-45c7-a313-09e824ad0ab6  

03/20/2013 13:45:51.06  w3wp.exe (0x0538)   0x0E04  InfoPath Forms Services Runtime - Data Connections  13zi    Verbose Web Request:  Copying response to DOMs  3f60b8ac-bf8a-45c7-a313-09e824ad0ab6  

03/20/2013 13:45:51.06  w3wp.exe (0x0538)   0x0E04  InfoPath Forms Services Runtime - Data Connections  13zi    Verbose Web Request:  Copying response to DOMs  3f60b8ac-bf8a-45c7-a313-09e824ad0ab6  

03/20/2013 13:45:51.06  w3wp.exe (0x0538)   0x0E04  InfoPath Forms Services Runtime - Data Connections  6qh8    Verbose Web Request: Ends url=http://webservice.com:7863/INERFACE/INTERFACE action=http://webservice.com/DisposalsValidation    3f60b8ac-bf8a-45c7-a313-09e824ad0ab6  

03/20/2013 13:45:51.06  w3wp.exe (0x0538)   0x0E04  InfoPath Forms Services Runtime - Data Connections  6wdi    Verbose WebServiceQuery: End    3f60b8ac-bf8a-45c7-a313-09e824ad0ab6  

03/20/2013 13:45:51.06  w3wp.exe (0x0538)   0x0E04  InfoPath Forms Services Runtime - Data Connections  eq8m    Warning The following data connection (domain\user1) has timed out(User: Disposal, Form Name: , IP: http://internal.com/collab/ServicesForms/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XsnLocation=http://internal.com/collab/ServicesForms/Disposal/Forms/template.xsn&SaveLocation=http://internal.com/collab/ServicesForms/Disposal&ClientInstalled=true&Source=http://internal.com/collab/ServicesForms/Disposal/Forms/AllItems.aspx&DefaultItemOpen=1, Request: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:Disposal:-myXSD-2013-03-19T06-58-00, Form ID: (null)).    3f60b8ac-bf8a-45c7-a313-09e824ad0ab6  

03/20/2013 13:45:51.06  w3wp.exe (0x0538)   0x0E04  InfoPath Forms Services Runtime 8z3p    Verbose Calling GlobalStorage.SetItem with index LastExceptionLogged value type DataAdapterException.   3f60b8ac-bf8a-45c7-a313-09e824ad0ab6  

03/20/2013 13:45:51.06  w3wp.exe (0x0538)   0x0E04  InfoPath Forms Services Runtime d1at    Verbose PostbackPage.PlayEventLog:http://internal.com/_layouts/Postback.FormServer.aspx finished in:00:00:10.0498937.   3f60b8ac-bf8a-45c7-a313-09e824ad0ab6
03/20/2013 13:45:51.06  w3wp.exe (0x0538)   0x0E04  InfoPath Forms Services Runtime c1jc    Verbose DataObject.Serialize.Save for XML name: finished in:00:00:00.0000871.   3f60b8ac-bf8a-45c7-a313-09e824ad0ab6  

03/20/2013 13:45:51.06  w3wp.exe (0x0538)   0x0E04  InfoPath Forms Services Runtime c1jc    Verbose DataObject.Serialize.Save for XML name:DisposalsValidation finished in:00:00:00.0001880.    3f60b8ac-bf8a-45c7-a313-09e824ad0ab6  

03/20/2013 13:45:51.06  w3wp.exe (0x0538)   0x0E04  InfoPath Forms Services Runtime 7nek    Verbose Disposing all cached sites. 3f60b8ac-bf8a-45c7-a313-09e824ad0ab6
03/20/2013 13:45:51.06  w3wp.exe (0x0538)   0x0E04  InfoPath Forms Services Runtime 8z3q    Verbose Calling GlobalStorage.RemoveAll!    3f60b8ac-bf8a-45c7-a313-09e824ad0ab6

03/20/2013 13:45:51.06  w3wp.exe (0x0538)   0x0E04  InfoPath Forms Services Runtime wdqm    Verbose GlobalStorage.Leave: Old context - FormControl   Total contexts after Leave - 0 3f60b8ac-bf8a-45c7-a313-09e824ad0ab6  

03/20/2013 13:45:51.06  w3wp.exe (0x0538)   0x0E04  SharePoint Server   State Service   8kfs    Medium  The StateManager is disposing and calling ReleaseLockedStates() (Count=0)   3f60b8ac-bf8a-45c7-a313-09e824ad0ab6
```

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?
I've the same problem on my farm

Comment: try 2 things, it depends on your setup.

1. add bypass proxy setting to web.config
<system.net>
     <defaultProxy>
        <proxy usesystemdefault = "false" proxyaddress="http://proxy.company.com:8080" bypassonlocal="true" />
     </defaultProxy>
</system.net>

2. If you have multiple WFE's then add local host address to the host file (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts)
add 127.0.0.1

Plz update on how you go.